# check if a string starts with number using regular expression

Tags: regex, logstash, filebeat

I am writing a filebeat configuration when I am matching if a line starts with a number like 03:32:33 ( a timestamp). I am currently doing it by-

```
\d
```

But its not getting recognised, is there anything else which I should do. I am not particularly good/ have experience with regex. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The real problem is that *filebeat* [does not support `\d`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/regexp-support.html#unsupported-regexp-patterns).

Replace `\d` by `[0-9]` and your regular expression will work.

I suggest you to give a look at the filebeat's [Supported Patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/regexp-support.html).

Also, be sure you've used `^`, it stands for the start of the string.

Answer (score 6):

```
Regex: (^\d)

1st Capturing group (^\d)
    ^ Match at the start of the string
    \d match a digit [0-9]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

`^([0-9]{2}:?){3}`

---

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tS7pQ9/1)

---

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([0-9]{2}:?){3}»
   Exactly 3 times «{3}»
      You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «{3}»
      Or, if you don’t want to capture anything, replace the capturing group with a non-capturing group to make your regex more efficient.
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
   Match the character “:” literally «:?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

The character ^ matches the start of a line.